# How to upload same file twice in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, upload

I am using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

I am taking file input in a dialog, my flow is as follows:

User open dialog, Upload File, User Closes the dialog

The issue is, when the user opens the dialog next time, without refreshing the page (obviously), the previous file name is still there next to "browse" button. But when user click on upload, it doesn't upload the same file, even if the user re select the same file. I know it has something to do with the onchange event but how to solve this in angularjs?

I tried resetting the model attached to file input, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set replaceFileInput config to true